# error: wp-admin/includes/translation-install.php on line 59

Tags: php, wordpress

I installed latest version of wordpress 4.4.2. using cpanel app install software...

In setting, edit and update error occurred :

**Warning:** An unexpected error occurred. Something may be wrong with WordPress.org or this server’s configuration. If you continue to have problems, please try the support forums. (WordPress could not establish a secure connection to WordPress.org. Please contact your server administrator.) in `/home/climbuse/public_html/climbusengineering.com/wp-admin/includes/translation-install.php` on line 59

How to fix ... 
Advance thanks for all...

Answer (score 3):

In my case it was the proxy blocking the communication with Wordpress server.

I fixed it by following [this guide](https://www.danbishop.org/2013/10/14/using-wordpress-behind-a-proxy/). <sup>[mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20220425201344/https://www.danbishop.org/2013/10/14/using-wordpress-behind-a-proxy/)</sup>

Basically I had to define these rules into `wp-config.php`:

```js
/* Configure proxy Server */
define('WP_PROXY_HOST', 'x.x.x.x');
define('WP_PROXY_PORT', '8080');
define('WP_PROXY_USERNAME', '');
define('WP_PROXY_PASSWORD', '');
define('WP_PROXY_BYPASS_HOSTS', 'localhost');
```

Comment: Dude, you're the best :)

Answer (score 0):

Login to FTP
Navigate to wp-includes directory and replace wp-includes/includes/translation-install.php after downloading a fresh WordPress zip from here : https://wordpress.org/download/

That should help fix it.

Comment: Already WP 4.4.2 latest version installed ... to confirm replace /translation-install.php

Answer (score 0):

You must run newr php. or you must replace in "ext" folder openssl extentesion to new version (to openssl 1.0.2e)... Wordpress 3.9.11 work with erlier openssl but wordpress 4 dosn't...

Answer (score 0):

Check "Plugins / Add New" page. If there is same error instead of featured plugins list, then it basically means that WebServer can't connect to the web. Try temporary disable firewall and see if problem is solved. And if it is - you need to add rules for outgoing traffic for your WebServer (httpd in Apache case).

Other option is check, if SSL module enabled in your WebServer (mod_ssl in Apache).

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue as well looks like wordpress.org was down and taken with it a lot of sites that are using the following function (in file wp-admin/includes/translation-install.php on line 59
):

```
function translations_api( $type, $args = null ) {
```

...

To solve it until wordpress.org will return I exited the function before it executing anything.

```
function translations_api( $type, $args = null ) {
      return;
```

Comment: thanks, it did fix the warning message for me and "translationPress" plugin still works apparently.